IntelliJ: Confirmation window before commiting
Sometimes I commit wrong comments, accidentally or otherwise. I want an option where this could not happen in one step, but I get a pop-up confirmation to revise my message.
In IntelliJ is there an option in the comment section, before I commit I get a confirmation popup - do you want to commit this message, etc?
Is there perhaps a plugin for this?


As long as you haven't pushed your commit, you can edit the commit message. In the Git tool window, Log tab, right-click the commit for which you want to change the commit message and Select Edit Commit Message.
Edit the commit message in the popup.
